# jquery datatable first column searching and sorting not works

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

i m working with web project here i have there web pages which have grid view for displaying records. now for better performance i use searching and sorting , pagging with jquery datatable js. it's works fine other columns but not sorting and  searching with only first column.

here i include my html code :

```
<script src="plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- IMPORTANT! Load jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js before bootstrap.min.js to fix bootstrap tooltip conflict with jquery ui tooltip -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery.cokie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datatables/extensions/Scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="scripts/metronic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/table-advanced.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            Metronic.init(); // init metronic core components
            Layout.init(); // init current layout
            Demo.init(); // init demo features
            TableAdvanced.init();
        });
    </script>
```

and here i just use this code for take effect on grid view :

```
protected void egrd_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (egrd.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            egrd.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            egrd.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        }
    }
```

all things works fine but i can't sort and search first column content.
what's wrong with this.

Comment: It is possible the TableAdvanced.init(); has options!

Comment: means i didnt get you.

Comment: I not worked with "TableAdvanced", but i know most of client side widgets has options. and i thin it is possible to forget an option.

Comment: @isaeid-ya i got something here for disable first column searching and sorting here can u please visit this https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21164/disable-sorting-of-one-column